# What is the difference between these two prototypes?

Tags: c++

```
 1.  A a;
     A b = a;
 2.  A a,b;
     b = a;
```

What is the difference between these two operator =?

Does the first one needs a prototype?

Answer (score 9):

In 1, `a` is default-constructed and `b` is copy-constructed from `a`. There is no assignment going on.

In 2, both `a` and `b` are default-constructed and then the value of `a` is assigned to `b`.

Comment: Last line seems off: "b is assigned to the value of a"?

Comment: @Mike: More specifically, in 1, `b` is copy-initialized.

Comment: @pst: sounds fine to me. Maybe it'll sound better without the to there.

Comment: Why not just, "the value of `a` is assigned to `b`", to avoid the transitive :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are not prototypes, instead it is creating objects of class A. In the first case statement `A b = a;` invokes the copy constructor of `A` where as the second case `A a,b` uses the default constructor of `A` to create objects and then use assignment operator of `A` for `b=a`.